# run c# application and return data to MATLAB

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I know the line below will run my c# application from within MATLAB.

```
dos(['C:\MyLocation\bin\Release\MyApp.exe']);
```

What I would like to know is how to return data (an array of numbers) from my c# application to a MATLAB variable?

**Update**

Thanks to Alyafey I can use the line below in matlab to run my c# application and return a value.

```
 [status,cmdout] = system(command,'-echo')
```

However I am not sure in my c# application how to return a value. My code is written inside a console application so the code enters and exits at static void Main. I know I can change the main function to return an integer however the number I need to return is a double. How do I go about this? I assume using a console application is wrong?

Comment: What about using [status, result] = system(cmd,'-echo');

Comment: Oh just seen that method on matlab, that's pretty handy. In my c# application how do I return an array of doubles?

Comment: why not just write it to a file, CSV / xml / json etc in your C# app and then read the file in matlab?

Comment: I was going to do that however it's not what my boss wants. I have written the code in a console application. I'm guessing that's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help, it's not an application but you can create c# library instead of app.

First create your c# app which do such a sample such this.

```
using System;

namespace MatlabLib
{
    public class MatlabHandler
    {
        public static double[] GetNums()
        {
            var db = new double[10];
            var r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                db[i] = r.Next();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }
}
```

then in matlab you can do this.

```
%%path to dll file
dllPath = fullfile('c:','MatlabLib.dll');

%%load dll
NET.addAssembly(dllPath);


%% get class by calling it's name started by namespace 
obj = MatlabLib.MatlabHandler

%%calling static function
mlData = obj.GetNums;

%% convert result to array of double
l = double(mlData);
```

You can refer to this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-net-methods.html) for more details on matlab doc center.